# Remove properties from Javascript object and create array

Tags: javascript

I have an object in which its properties contain arrays of objects.
I want to create just one array with every object inside of every array inside of each property of this object. Hehe, its a little confusing.

Basically I have this and I want just one array with every value of these arrays.

```
{
AdvoodleSign: Array(1)
Arbeit und Dienstleistung: Array(6)
Datenschutz und KYC: Array(5)
Ehe und Familie: Array(4)
Gesellschaftsgründung: Array(8)
Immobilie: Array(13)
Sonstige Verträge: Array(12)
Vorsorge und Bevollmächtigung: Array(7)
Weitere Verträge: Array(0)
Änderungen in der Gesellschaft: Array(7)
}
```

This is what I did, it works... but it seems to me that it must be a better/cleaner way.

```
const values = Object.values(data)
var contract_templates = [];
   for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      for (var j = values[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
      {
          contract_templates.push(values[i][j]);
      }
   }
return contract_templates;
```

contract_templates should contain every object inside of the arrays of above:

```
contract_templates = [obj, obj, obj, obj...];
```

Comment: Please provide the desired output format.

Comment: If the function works, you could always try going over to code review @ https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Edited with the desired output format. Code review, that's cool! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

If you are using modern browsers, you can use this 
`Object.values(yourobj).flat()`